# sql json not working

Tags: php, sql, json

i have created a php script which get the value from the database saves it in json

```
$sql = "SELECT detail FROM BUNK WHERE id = '".$id."'";
$sql2 = "SELECT yes FROM BUNK WHERE id = '".$id."'";
$sql3 = "SELECT depend FROM BUNK WHERE id = '".$id."'";
$sql4 = "SELECT no FROM BUNK WHERE id = '".$id."'";

$result1 = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
$json['detail'] = $result1;
echo json_encode($json);

$result2 = mysqli_query($link,$sql2);
$json['yes'] = $result2;
echo json_encode($json);

$result3 = mysqli_query($link,$sql3);
$json['depend'] = $result3;
echo json_encode($json);

$result4 = mysqli_query($link,$sql4);
$json['no'] = $result4;
echo json_encode($json);
```

but i'm getting result as:

```
{"detail":{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}}{"detail":{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null},"yes":{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}}{"detail":{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null},"yes":{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null},"depend":{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}}{"detail":{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null},"yes":{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null},"depend":{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null},"no":{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Why not do this all in one query?

Comment: @chris85 new in phph.. :)

Comment: You can perform only one query ( `SELECT detail, yes, depend, no FROM ...` ), then you have to fetch the query (see [these examples](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)). Last but not least, you have to encode only once, otherwise your JSON object is not valid.

Comment: thanks a lot guys...!!

Comment: Also, echo the JSON only once, after it is complete, not after each time you add to it.

Answer (score 0):

Basic:

```
$sql    = "SELECT detail, yes, depend, no FROM BUNK WHERE id = '".$id."'";
$result = mysqli_query( $link, $sql ) or die( $link->mysqli_error );
$rows   = mysqli_fetch_all( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC );

$json   = json_encode( $rows );
```

This is only basic, because:

1. If your `id` come from user input (a HTML form, i.e.), you have to consider [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php);
2. If you want to customize JSON string, you have to use a loop with [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) instead of using `mysqli_fetch_all`

`$json` is the resulting JSON string. To output it:

```
echo $json;
```